# checkbox event only on check, not on uncheck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I want my code to put value 1 in the database if a checkbox is checked and 0 if it gets unchecked. However, my current code only updates the row to 1, but not to 0. I've been banging my head on this for the last hour, which is really frustrating.

**Javascript**

```
$('#onoffswitch6').change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked'); //true or false?
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "call.php", 
        data: { onOrOff : checked } 
    });
});
```

**call.php**

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['onOrOff']))
{
    if ($_POST['onOrOff'] == false) {
        global $onOrOff;
        $onOrOff = 0;
    } else if ($_POST['onOrOff'] == true) {
        global $onOrOff;
        $onOrOff = 1;
    };

$qry = "UPDATE member SET checkbox='$onOrOff' WHERE id='$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die("An error occurred ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Where is your cdoe for unchecked as there is for checked?

Comment: Have you done any logging to see if the script executes properly?

Comment: Can do `var checked = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Yes, the javascript part executes properly (it gives console logs for true and false), so the mistake must be in the PHP part.

Comment: passing javascript false to HTTP post likely would be passing a empty string instead of false.. You may want to output it like tymeJV suggests, use a literal to replace true / false then it may make the variable passing easier.

Comment: @MoeTsao Do I just copy/paste his code? Or? I haven't done a literal replace before...

Comment: use $('#onoffswitch6').on("click", function() {...

Comment: @user3290485 Yes his code for javascript should work, and PHP should take 1 / 0 as true / false naturally.  Have you tried echo the POST variable you received in PHP? That should reveal the problem right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`false` should be `'false'`

`true` should be `'true'`

Php does not treat the ajax passed value as boolean but it does treate `$_POST['onOrOff']` as a string, make run this code, do something like this.

```
if ($_POST['onOrOff'] == 'false') {
    global $onOrOff;
    $onOrOff = 0;
} else if ($_POST['onOrOff'] == 'true') {
    global $onOrOff;
    $onOrOff = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In php, you are checking if the value is true/false, but what's coming in is a string of "true" or "false". Change it to

```
if ($_POST['onOrOff'] == "false") {...
```

or something like

```
$onOrOff = ($_POST['onOrOff'] == "true" ? 1 : 0);
```